# Проблемы с коллекцией ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Приветствую.

Есть класс:

```
class ItemsC1
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Ping { get; set; }

   public ItemsC1(string ID, string Ping)
    {
        this.ID = ID;
        this.Ping = Ping;
    }
}
```

Нужно заменить элемент в этом классе на новый.

```
public partial class VrMonitor : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<ItemsC1> collection1 = new ObservableCollection<ItemsC1>();
    public VrMonitor()
    {
        collection1[0] = new ItemsC1 {ID="sdf",Ping="5"}; 
    }
}
```

Но не выходит, пишет:

> NameSPD.ItemsC1 не содержит конструктор, который принимает 0 аргументов

Мне нужно в определенном элементе, например, collection1[5], изменить свойство Ping. Как такое можно сделать с этой коллекцией?

**Обновление**

Ну, если точно известен индекс, и там не null, то можно в лоб:

```
collection1[5].Ping = "новое значение"
```

Значение не null, значение меняется, но ObservableCollection прикреплён к ListView при таком добавлении в лоб, ListView не обновляет значение.

Вы уверены в правильности выбора типов переменных? В данном примере не уверен, пример просто для теста.

**Обновление 2**

Благодарю, то что нужно. В Интернете нашёл код при использовании кидает исключение. Ну да ладно, ваш код понятен и работает в моём случае. Спасибо!

```
public class People : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

      private string _firstName;

      public string FirstName
      {
            get { return _firstName; }
            set
            {
                _firstName = value;
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("FirstName"));
            }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибка в строке

```
collection1[0] = new ItemsC1 {ID="sdf",Ping="5"};
```

Вы же сами описали класс с единственным конструктором, принимающим два аргумента, а приведенная выше строка "ищет" конструктор без аргументов. Эта запись эквивалентна

```
var a = new ItemsC1();
a.ID = "sdf";
a.Ping = "5";
```

Решения тут два:

1. Вызвать таки описанный Вами конструктор: `collection[0] = new ItemsC1("sdf", "5");`. Что логичнее, если эти поля класса обязательные.
2. Описать конструктор, который не будет принимать никаких аргументов:

   public ItemsC1()
   {

   }

> Мне нужно в определенном элементе, например collection1[5], изменить свойство Ping. Как такое можно сделать с этой коллекцией?

Ну, если точно известен индекс, и там не `null`, то можно в лоб:

```
collection1[5].Ping = "новое значение"
```

Если же индекс неизвестен, то сначала надо найти нужный элемент. Можно "по-старинке" перебором, а можно прибегнуть к помощи `LINQ`:

```
ItemC1 item = collecion1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == "sdf");
if (item != null)
{
    // Нашли нужный элемент
    item.Ping = "новое значение";
}
```

**P.S.** Вы уверены в правильности выбора типов переменных?

---

Реализация `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class ItemsC1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; // Событие изменения данных

    // Для удобства оборачиваем вызов события в метод
    private void RaisePropetyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _ping;

    public string Ping
    {
        get { return _ping; }
        set
        {
            if (_ping == value)
                return;
            _ping = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Ping"); // Сообщаем об изменении
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь при изменении свойства `Ping`, `ListView` узнает об этом.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: @updat, быть такого не может. Покажите код.

Comment: Вырвал кусочек, надеюсь, код будет понятен. Обработка в потоке, потому что нагрузка большая, форма зависает. http://dim.st/t8455.txt

Comment: > ObservableCollection прикреплён к ListView при таком добавлении в лоб, ListView не обновляет значение

Дак это уже совсем другой вопрос! Вам нужно реализовать интерфейс [INotifyPropertyChanged][1] для Вашего класса `ItemsC1`.


[1]:http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Вы можете показать, как реализовать такой интерфейс в моём примере для поля Ping?

Comment: Обновил ответ

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: @updat, может, в Вашем случае `PropertyChanged == null`. В любом случае пробегитесь отладчиком, и все встанет на свои места.